# Opening the upnp stream from command line

Tags: raspbmc, streaming

I am streaming my audio output from my Ubuntu laptop to my raspberry pi running raspbmc over upnp. I do this by creating a upnp device via rygel and then open the stream using the GUI of raspbmc. This all works fine.

Now I am wondering if it is possible to open the stream from command line instead of using the GUI. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So your RPi acts like a DLNA renderer, and your laptop acts like a DLNA server & DLNA player, right?

Comment: @MorganCourbet That's correct

Answer (score 1):

[GMediaRender](http://gmrender.nongnu.org/) should do the trick. It is a UPNP media renderer running as a daemon. I've once succeeded in installing and running this soft on my RPi.

A [couple](http://blog.scphillips.com/2014/05/playing-music-on-a-raspberry-pi-using-upnp-and-dlna-v3/) [of](http://www.coraline.org/non-fiction/raspi-upnp-renderer) [tutorials](http://chrisbaume.wordpress.com/2012/06/24/raspberry-pi-upnp-media-player/) explain how to install it on a Pi. It is quite tricky, but possible. I think I have followed the first link.

If you are brave enough, I suggest you to share your experience by answering your own question and explain step-by-step the procedure to install GMediaRender.

Comment: I have installed and setup the GMMediaRender, but I do not understand how I can use it to open the stream published by my laptop via rygel. From what I see in the configuration file it seems that GMMediaRender is publishing a name itself, but I cannot select this name as an audio output device, so it is probably not that.

Comment: You are on the same network than the RPi, right? Also, make sure GMediaRender is running on the Pi with `ps aux | grep render` (not sure of the name).

Comment: Yes, but it seems as if I should push the audio to GMediaRender using the name it publishes, instead of GMediaRender opening the stream I publish from my laptop

Comment: @TmKVU Well, there are three elements: the server (where your media is stored), the player (controls the media to be played), and the renderer (plays the media). I don't really know how it works (whether the renderer pulls the content, or the server pushes to the renderer). If you have an android phone, you can install [BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp). It acts as a player (ie a remote control). It will list the servers the renderers.

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear enough, but I am streaming my audio output to the Raspberry Pi. On my Ubuntu laptop I can select Upnp as output instead of my build in speakers. There are no media files involved

Comment: @TmKVU Oh, OK I understand. I didn't know that we could broadcast a continuous stream through UPnP. Well, if I find something relevant, I'll edit my answer (probably tomorrow).